# Conditional lag with dates in R - how to code skip to next date if dates are the same?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm stuck on how to conditionally lag a date variable within the same ID group, but skip the next date value and lag the one after if it is the same as the original date.
To illustrate,

```
data have
ID Value Date
a 50 1987-01-01
a 52 1987-01-01
a 33 1989-05-03
b 10 1979-08-28
b 52 1988-02-23
b 45 1988-02-23
b 33 1988-02-23
b 40 1990-05-20

data want
ID Value Date Lead_date
a 50 1987-01-01 1989-05-03
a 52 1987-01-01 1989-05-03
a 33 1989-05-03 NA
b 10 1979-08-28 1988-02-23
b 52 1988-02-23 1990-05-20
b 45 1988-02-23 1990-05-20
b 33 1988-02-23 1990-05-20
b 40 1990-05-20 NA
```

I'm not sure if there is an elegant way of doing this, or if I need a for loop?

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: *"lag a date variable"* into a variable named `Lead_date` ... :-/

Comment: my bad for using lag/lead interchangeably in my question..  more accurately, it is -1, "lag"  ;)

Comment: But your expected output has the next value, not the previous, which suggests _lead_ (`shift(Date, type="lead")`, in `data.table`-speak).

Comment: Ah ok! I've been clumsy and writing shift(Date, -1, type="lag"), which achieves the same result but lead is much more elegant! thanks :)

Comment: My point is that the direction of the shift is contradicting. Assuming that the data is ordered (at least) by `Date`, "lag" would mean that the preceding row's value would be used, resulting in a `Date` that is _before this row's value; `

Answer (score 5):

**1)** `findInterval` will find the position of the last Date matching the current one so just add 1 to get the position of the next Date.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(DF)
DF[, Lead_date := Date[findInterval(Date, Date) + 1], by = ID]

DF
##    ID Value       Date  Lead_date
## 1:  a    50 1987-01-01 1989-05-03
## 2:  a    52 1987-01-01 1989-05-03
## 3:  a    33 1989-05-03       <NA>
## 4:  b    10 1979-08-28 1988-02-23
## 5:  b    52 1988-02-23 1990-05-20
## 6:  b    45 1988-02-23 1990-05-20
## 7:  b    33 1988-02-23 1990-05-20
## 8:  b    40 1990-05-20       <NA>
```

**2)** An alternative is to get the position of the match of Date to the unique dates and then take the next unique date:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
DF[, Lead_date := { u <- unique(Date); u[match(Date, u) + 1] }, by = ID]
```

**3)** Another way is to replace duplicated dates with NA and then use na.locf0 to fill them in taking the next date.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

setDF(DF)
DF[, Lead_Date := replace(Date, duplicated(Date), NA) |>
                    na.locf0(fromLast = TRUE) |>
                    shift(-1), by = ID]
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "ID Value Date
a 50 1987-01-01
a 52 1987-01-01
a 33 1989-05-03
b 10 1979-08-28
b 52 1988-02-23
b 45 1988-02-23
b 33 1988-02-23
b 40 1990-05-20"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! For my knowledge, when using findInterval I will need to sort the dataset by ID and Date first, is that right? ie do setkey(DF, ID, Date)

Comment: Yes, these answers assume that Date is sorted within ID., which was the case in the sample data in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(d, d["ID"]),
                      function(x) {
                        ld <- rle(x$Date)
                        ld$values <- c(ld$values[-1], NA)
                        x$Lead_date <- inverse.rle(ld)
                        x}
                      
))
```

#### The data

```
d <- read.table(text="ID Value Date
a 50 1987-01-01
a 52 1987-01-01
a 33 1989-05-03
b 10 1979-08-28
b 52 1988-02-23
b 45 1988-02-23
b 33 1988-02-23
b 40 1990-05-20", header=TRUE)
```